# Getting a position:fixed sidebar to stop at footer (and adding JS to Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, position, wordpress-theming, footer

Apologies if this seems simple, but I am really struggling here and new to JS so not sure if I am just missing something!!!

Page: https://www.villaslegianbali.com/reviews/

I have added the sidebar to allow people to find the reviews they want. However, it appears over the footer. I tried changing the `z-index` (sidebar to 0, footer to 99) for now, but even that isn't working.

When I try to save the below JS, it comes up with an error:

> "Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 325 of file wp-content/themes/villalegianbali/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.
>
> syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting end of file"
>
> (line 325 is the first line of the JS above)

Code:

```js
//JS I added to the functions.php file:
var sideNav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
var footer = document.querySelector('.footer');

function checkOffset() {
  function getRectTop(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.top;
  }

  if ((getRectTop(sideNav) + document.body.scrollTop) + sideNav.offsetHeight >= (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop) - 10)
    sideNav.style.position = 'absolute';
  if (document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop))
    sideNav.style.position = 'fixed'; // restore when you scroll up

  sideNav.innerHTML = document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  checkOffset();
});
```

```css
.footer {
  height: 243px;
  z-index: 999 !important
}

.sidenav {
  width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav-parent">
  <div class="sidenav reviews-menu" style="position: fixed; float: left; bottom:0; margin-left: -30px; margin-bottom: 15px">
    <h4 class="reviews-menu-title">Choose your Villa:</h4>
    <a href="#karma" margin="0">
      <h3 class="reviews-menu-item">Villa Karma Legian</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="#poppy" margin="0">
      <h3 class="reviews-menu-item">Villa Poppy Legian</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="#aniela" margin="0">
      <h3 class="reviews-menu-item">Villa Aniela</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="#segara" margin="0">
      <h3 class="reviews-menu-item">Villa Segara Legian</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="#tropical" margin="0">
      <h3 class="reviews-menu-item">Tropical House</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="#zakira" margin="0">
      <h3 class="reviews-menu-item">Villa Zakira Legian</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
(content)
```

Comment: I created a JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/scypb5en/

I have tried so many different JS/JQuery codes and NONE seem to work!!

Answer (score 0):

Please put below CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .footer {
        z-index: 99 !important;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

We can't directly put Javascript in the functions.php file. To add JS first save in the .js file and include it in the functions.php file.

```
For example. Follow below steps
1] Create a .js file as name scrollToTop.js
2] Put the below code in that JS file

var sideNav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
var footer = document.querySelector('.footer');

function checkOffset() {
  function getRectTop(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.top;
  }
  
  if((getRectTop(sideNav) + document.body.scrollTop) + sideNav.offsetHeight >= (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop) - 10)
    sideNav.style.position = 'absolute';
  if(document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop))
    sideNav.style.position = 'fixed'; // restore when you scroll up
  
  sideNav.innerHTML = document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  checkOffset();
});
```

3] Put the below code in the functions.php file and check.

```
function villas_adding_scripts_for_scroll() {
    wp_register_script('villas_scrolltop_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scrollToTop.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('villas_scrolltop_script');
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'villas_adding_scripts_for_scroll', 999 );
```

Comment: Thank you!!! 

The css now has the sidebar going behind the footer, but not stopping it above.

Any ideas how to fix this?